# Printing the minimum and maximum of an array

Tags: c, arrays, max, min

I'm having a problem with finding the minimum and maximum value in an array.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int maximum(int array[], int n);
int minimum(int array[], int n);

int main() 
{ 
    int array[0];
    int count, i;
    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", count);
    printf("Enter the elements of the array:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    printf("Maximum: %d", maximum(array, count)); 
    printf("Minimum: %d", minimum(array, count));
    return 0; 
} 

int maximum(int array[], int n) 
{ 
    int i; 
    int max = array[0]; 
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) 
    {
        if (array[i] > max) 
            max = array[i]; 
    }
    return max; 
} 

int minimum(int array[], int n)
{
    int i; 
    int min = array[0]; 
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) 
    {
        if (array[i] < min) 
            min = array[i]; 
    }
    return min; 
}
```

The code produces the following code after compilation (No warnings or errors):

```
Enter the size of the array:
```

I can enter a number, but then it finishes the program.
What is causing my program to do this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Probably because of incorrect use of scanf: it should be `scanf("%d", &count);`

Comment: `int array[0]` defines an array capable of holding zero values! You cannot "scanf into array[something]" because the array has no elements.

Comment: ...so it is just as well that the uninitialised `count` happens to be `<= 0` although the two functions exhibit *undefined behaviour* by accessing `array[0]`. After correcting the `&count` error, you can move the array definition below the `scanf` as `int array[count];` (assuming VLA is supported).

Comment: @GoodDeeds. Fixed it, but still produces garbage output

Comment: @pmg So how would I fix this so it does place values into the array?

Comment: I edited my last comment to show how - now see Vlad's thorough answer.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, by the way. It is much appreciated.

Comment: Everything works! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

This declaration

```
int array[0];
```

is invalid and does not make sense.

Also this call

```
scanf("%d", count);
```

has undefined behavior. You have to write

```
scanf("%d", &count);
```

Also as the elements of the passed array are not changed in the functions the first function parameter should have the qualifier const.

Pay attention to that in general the user can pass as the second argument the value equal to 0. In this case your functions will have undefined behavior.

Your updated program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h> 

size_t maximum( const int array[], size_t n ); 
size_t minimum( const int array[], size_t n ); 

int main( void ) 
{
    printf( "Enter the size of the array: " );

    size_t count;

    scanf( "%zu", &count );

    int array[count];

    printf("Enter the elements of the array:\n");
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    printf("Maximum: %d\n", array[maximum( array, count )] ); 
    printf("Minimum: %d\n", array[minimum( array, count )] );

    return 0; 
} 

size_t maximum( const int array[], size_t n ) 
{ 
    size_t max_i = 0;
    ; 
    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( array[max_i] < array[i] ) max_i = i; 
    }

    return max_i; 
} 

size_t minimum( const int array[], size_t n ) 
{ 
    size_t min_i = 0;
    ; 
    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( array[i] < array[min_i] ) min_i = i; 
    }

    return min_i; 
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter the size of the array: 10
Enter the elements of the array: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Maximum: 9
Minimum: 0
```

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect, and works properly. Thank you for your all of your help.

Comment: @WeatherVane it is in fact the same as to return the first iterator in algorithms in C++ when the first iterator is equal to the last iterator.

Comment: @WeatherVane The functions will return 0 and array[0] will yields -1. What is the problem?

Comment: @WeatherVane It seems you did not look through the code attentively.;)

Comment: Uh ok, you are tracking the index, not the value but there was no need to change that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the address of *count* in this **scanf** call:

```
scanf("%d", &count);
```